# Django template is not displaying correct information

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django template and a view. In the view, there is a query that will check to see if the user and view have a record in the friend table. In the template, if the query comes up as empty, it will display to send a friend request. If the query comes back with objects, it will not display the option to send a request. I have the following if statement to display the request if the `friends.objects` is empty.

```
{% if friends == None %}
  <a href="{% url 'user_request' username=view.username %}">Send Request</a>
{% endif %}
```

For some reason, when the query `friends` is empty, it is not displaying the message. when the query `friends` is not empty, it is still not displaying the message. I checked if it has to do with the query but it is unrelated to the query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty list does not mean it is None. Check

`{% if friends|length %}
  <a href="{% url 'user_request' username=view.username %}">Send Request</a>
{% endif %}`